# Implementing concurrent processing in Web Service (ASMX), control Service performance

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

This question is about implementing load balancing in Web Service (ASMX). Not WCF.

I created Web Service (ASMX) and I have one WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Extracting data from the image.")]
public PersonData GetInfo(byte[] image)
{
     PersonData data = new PersonData();
     IFlexiCaptureProcessor processor = fcWebServiceProcessorsPool.GetProcessor();
     processor.AddImageFile(image);
     IDocument document = processor.RecognizeNextDocument();
     data.Number = document.Sections[0];
     data.Date = document.Sections[1];
     return data;
}
```

I have 5 processors in my fcWebServiceProcessorsPool - processors amount depends on amount of CPU cores. 
I need to create another WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<PersonData> GetInfo(List<byte[]> images)
{
   //foreach byte[] image in images
   //...the same code
}
```

But I have not ideas how to implement concurrent processing.
What I expect:

- 1 request = 100 images;  5 processors are free => 5 loaded processors
  with 20    images each.
- 6 requests in one moment = 1 image, 1 image, 20 images, 30 images, 40
  images, 50 images; 5 processors are free => 5 loaded processors, 1 request in
  queue.

1 task is 1 image. 
My goal - always equally load each processor.

How can I do this? This is my first Web Service so I know anything about it. I found a lot of articles about ThrottlingBehavior but it refers to WCF but my program is not WCF. I need some advice.

I use .NET Framework 4.5 and dll provided by my firm for processing images.

Comment: Load balancing over CPUs within same computer? ASP.NET will serve each request on a different thread (and you may work in parallel within each request), **framework, OS and CPU itself will do everything.** BTW cores load balancing isn't such easy. Consider, for example, if one core is boosted and one is off. Is it better to wake up that sleeping core and slow down the other one or to queue such request? How to manage cache locality? IMO don't try to manage these details unless you're really aware of what you're doing (and IMO ASP.NET is too high to have a clear view about them)

Comment: Also by the way, ASMX is not supported anymore. You should consider switching to [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: The question has nothing to do with load balancing. This is concurrent/parallel processing, which is handled by TPL, PLINQ and TPL DataFlow. The type of web framework is irrelevant here. The important question is what kind of processing do you want to perform on the images? Which .NET framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to consider to balance over CPUs/cores? Many things, for example:

- Turbo Boost (or equivalent technology). If you have two cores running at 3 GHz and two cores sleeping what's better? To wake up another core (slowing down first twos to 2 GHz) or queue tasks into those two cores?
- What's better for cache locality? Is it more efficient to queue a similar task in the same core because of cache (code and/or data)?
- Do you have any concern about power consumption?
- All cores are equally loaded? I do not mean only by your program but by system and background services/processes.
- Did you take into account basic ASP.NET infrastructure? Do you know where it's running? Moreover different .NET/ASP.NET versions behave different and tricks may don't work well with another one.

In general, from my point of view, these details are really at a very low level and in ASP.NET you don't have a clear view of what's going on in the system. Even if you do a serious research and you measure results what you may get is something valid for one single specific scenario (and with a single specific CPU/system architecture). Tuning this stuff is an hard thing and you need details (from run-time) and tests (from a big population where you collected statistical data). Moreover even if you *understand* what's better for your scenario you can't control all these things (for example you can't programmatically *wake up* a core).

ASP.NET will serve requests in different thread, what you can do is to do calculation in parallel. **.NET framework, underlying OS and finally CPU itself** have much more details to use to choose best approach and each one will work in concert for this.

You're programming for ASP.NET in C#, it's easier (and safer) to rely on such heavily tested and tuned components.

In code (assuming modern .NET even if .ASMX sounds old, in case you're running on .NET 2 you simply have to switch to a handmade `Parallel.ForEach` implementation that directly queues on `ThreadPool`). Please note this is just an example to sketch what I mean, not code you should really use in production:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<PersonData> GetInfo(List<byte[]> images)
{
    var result = new ConcurrentBag<PersonData>();

    Parallel.ForEach(images, image => {
        result.Add(GetInfo(image));
    });

    return result.ToList();
}
```

**To give an answer:** do not care about that details. Write parallel, scalable and concurrent code using highest tools (libraries, language and framework) you can use and let underlying layers aware of balancing.